# Different HTML pages with same codes look completely different

Tags: html, css

I'm very much in need of some help since I have some problems with my navigationbar. One of my buttons is a dropdown, but my dropdown content is stuck inside of the nav and I want it to drop right below it.

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 4000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -10%;
  margin-left: -1%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  width: 110%;
  padding-bottom: -3%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 10;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
  color: #ff3385;
  text-decoration: underline #ff3385;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}


/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: list-item;
  margin text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: inherit;
  position: fixed:
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: white;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 100;
  margin-top: 25%;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: -0.75%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9.5%;
  margin-top: -27.1%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.h1 {
  font-size: 300%;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1.5%;
  font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
  font-size: 300%;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline #ff3385;
  color: #ff3385;
}

p {
  font-size: 150%;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.møbler {
  padding: 1%;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  float: left;
}

footer {
  color: black;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  clear: left;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 200%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Herningmøbelengros.dk</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Mastercss.css" />
  <script src="newjavascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#f5f5f0">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="index.html">Hjem</a>
        <a href="side 2.html" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Møbler</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Borde</a>
            <a href="#">Stole</a>
            <a href="#">Skabe</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <a href="side 3.html">Om os</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>





  <div class="logo">
    <img src="LOGO.PNG" alt="Herning Bolig engros møbler" align="center" style="width:30%" />
  </div>

  <section>
    <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:100px">
      <img class="mySlides" src="førsøgsbillede.jpg" style="width:53.3%" />
      <img class="mySlides" src="førsøgsbillede 2.jpg" style="width:53.3%" />
      <img class="mySlides" src="førsøgsbillede 3.jpg" style="width:53.3%" />
    </div>
  </section>


  <h1 class="h1">Køb stort - betal småt</h1>



  <hr>
  <footer>
    <div style='float:left; width:30%'>
      <strong>Kontakt</strong> <br>Telf: +45 21 42 28 99<br> Email:Jydskm@gmail.com
    </div>
    <div style='float:left; width:30%; margin-left:30px'>
      <strong>Lokation</strong> <br>Find os på Industrivej Syd 1B<br> 7400 Herning
    </div>
    <div style='float:left; width:30%; margin-left:30px'>
      <strong>Åbningstider</strong> <br>Ons-fre 10.00-17.00<br> Lør-søn 10.00-16.00
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to clarify what your problem actually is.

Comment: The fact that you didn't do your homework until the last minute is irrelevant on SO. Answers will come when they come, not on your schedule. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/215552

Answer (score 0):

You have a `<li>` elements without a preceding `<ul>` element. That's the first thing I really notice about your nav menu. You also have a bunch of inline styles, but you also have an external CSS document? It looks like you need to do some research on the basic syntax of HTML and CSS. You link to a W3 Schools stylesheet, so I assume you are familiar with that site. Use Google and search for how to create a proper dropdown menu with HTML and CSS. I guarantee it will be one of the first two or three results. Stack Overflow should really be used for when you've already done a bit of research and can't get the answer for exactly what you're trying to do.